# Javascript ES6 Booklist bug

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, dom-manipulation, swiper.js

App demo https://scannerbug.netlify.app/

This is a simple web app that checks the scanned barcode against an API and the data returned gets added to the booklist.

The problem is that at the first time I scan a book, only one gets added, the second time two books get added (this makes it three) and the third time three books get added (this makes it six books in the list). This way I get 6 books in the list when I only scanned three.

Can anyone help me? I will provide any information needed if you can't understand something in my code.

Pastebin JS Code: https://pastebin.com/dj7Pi1JE

```
//SWIPER SETTING
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
        effect: "coverflow",
        grabCursor: true,
        centeredSlides: true,
        slidesPerView: "auto",
        coverflowEffect: {
            rotate: 60,
            stretch: 0,
            depth: 150,
            modifier: 1,
            slideShadows: true,
        },
    });
});
//BOOK CLASS
 
class Book {
    constructor(url, cover, title, author, pages, isbn) {
        this.url = url;
        this.cover = cover;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.pages = pages;
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
}
 
//UI CLASS
class UI {
    static displayBooks() {
        // let swiper = document.querySelector(".swiper-container").swiper;
        // swiper.removeAllSlides();
        const storedBooks = [
            {
                url: "www.google.com",
                title: "Test Title",
                author: "Test Author",
                pages: "230",
                isbn: "9778621466124",
            },
            {
                url: "www.isbndb.com",
                title: "Test Title",
                author: "Test Author",
                pages: "100",
                isbn: "9778621466124",
            },
        ];
 
        const books = storedBooks;
 
        books.forEach((book) => UI.addBookToList(book));
    }
 
    static addBookToList(book) {
        //INIT SWIPER ONLY AFTER ADDING BOOKS
        let swiper = document.querySelector(".swiper-container").swiper;
 
        swiper.appendSlide(`
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="book-cover">
                <img src="${book.cover}" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="book-info">
                <h2 class="book-title">${book.title}</h2>
                <h3 class="book-author">By ${book.author}</h3>
                <p class="book-pages">Pages: ${book.pages}</p>
                <p>ISBN: ${book.isbn}</p>
            </div>
 
            <div class="cta-buttons">
                <a href="${book.url}" class="read-more btn" target="_blank">Read More</a>
                <a href="#" class="delete btn">Remove Book</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        `);
 
        swiper.update();
    }
 
    static deleteBook(element) {
        if (element.classList.contains("delete")) {
            element.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        }
 
        //INIT SWIPER ONLY AFTER ADDING BOOKS
        let swiper = document.querySelector(".swiper-container").swiper;
        swiper.update();
    }
 
    static clearFields() {
        document.querySelector("#result-form").reset();
    }
}
// STORAGE CLASS
 
//EVENT: DISPLAY BOOKS
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", UI.displayBooks);
//EVENT ADD A BOOK
function getMovies(searchText) {
    axios
        .get(
            `https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:${searchText}&format=json&jscmd=data`
        )
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            let path = `ISBN:${searchText}`;
            let data = response.data[`${path}`];
 
            let cover;
            if (data.cover) {
                cover = data.cover.medium;
            } else {
                cover = "./imgs/book-cover-placeholder.png";
            }
            let url = data.url;
            let title = data.title;
            let author = data.authors[0].name;
            let pages = data.number_of_pages;
            let isbn = searchText;
 
            const book = new Book(url, cover, title, author, pages, isbn);
 
            UI.addBookToList(book);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
 
// EVENT: REMOVE A BOOK
document.querySelector(".swiper-wrapper").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    UI.deleteBook(e.target);
});
 
//SCANNER CODE
document.getElementById("start-button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("search-input").value = "";
    let selectedDeviceId;
    const codeReader = new ZXing.BrowserBarcodeReader();
    console.log("ZXing code reader initialized");
 
    //GET THE VIDEO DEVICE
    codeReader
        .getVideoInputDevices()
        .then((videoInputDevices) => {
            const sourceSelect = document.getElementById("sourceSelect");
            selectedDeviceId = videoInputDevices[0].deviceId;
            if (videoInputDevices.length > 1) {
                videoInputDevices.forEach((element) => {
                    const sourceOption = document.createElement("option");
                    sourceOption.text = element.label;
                    sourceOption.value = element.deviceId;
                    sourceSelect.appendChild(sourceOption);
                });
 
                sourceSelect.onchange = () => {
                    selectedDeviceId = sourceSelect.value;
                };
 
                // const sourceSelectPanel = document.getElementById("sourceSelectPanel");
                // sourceSelectPanel.style.display = "block";
            }
 
            //DECODE BARCODE FROM CAMERA
            (() => {
                codeReader
                    .decodeOnceFromVideoDevice(selectedDeviceId, "video")
                    .then((result) => {
                        let searchText = result.text;
 
                        console.log(result);
                        document.getElementById("search-input").value = searchText;
 
                        //GET MOVIES WHEN ADD BUTTON IS CLICKED
                        document
                            .getElementById("add-button")
                            .addEventListener("click", () => {
                                getMovies(searchText);
 
                                UI.clearFields();
                            });
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.error(err);
                    });
            })();
 
            document.getElementById("stop-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
                codeReader.reset();
                console.log("Reset.");
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably because of the position of the following part of code:

```js
document
    .getElementById("add-button")
    .addEventListener("click", () => {
        getMovies(searchText);
 
        UI.clearFields();
    });
```

This snippet of code adds an event listener to the `#add-button` element *every time it's run*, i.e. after every scan.

To make your code work, move it to a top-level `DOMContentLoaded` listener, and change it into the following:

```js
document
    .getElementById("add-button")
    .addEventListener("click", () => {
        const searchText = document.getElementById("search-input").value;
        if(!searchText) return;
        
        getMovies(searchText);
 
        UI.clearFields();
    });
```

So, you should have something like this:

```js
//SWIPER SETTING
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
        effect: "coverflow",
        grabCursor: true,
        centeredSlides: true,
        slidesPerView: "auto",
        coverflowEffect: {
            rotate: 60,
            stretch: 0,
            depth: 150,
            modifier: 1,
            slideShadows: true,
        },
    });
});
//BOOK CLASS
 
class Book {
    constructor(url, cover, title, author, pages, isbn) {
        this.url = url;
        this.cover = cover;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.pages = pages;
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
}
 
//UI CLASS
class UI {
    static displayBooks() {
        // let swiper = document.querySelector(".swiper-container").swiper;
        // swiper.removeAllSlides();
        const storedBooks = [
            {
                url: "www.google.com",
                title: "Test Title",
                author: "Test Author",
                pages: "230",
                isbn: "9778621466124",
            },
            {
                url: "www.isbndb.com",
                title: "Test Title",
                author: "Test Author",
                pages: "100",
                isbn: "9778621466124",
            },
        ];
 
        const books = storedBooks;
 
        books.forEach((book) => UI.addBookToList(book));
    }
 
    static addBookToList(book) {
        //INIT SWIPER ONLY AFTER ADDING BOOKS
        let swiper = document.querySelector(".swiper-container").swiper;
 
        swiper.appendSlide(`
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="book-cover">
                <img src="${book.cover}" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="book-info">
                <h2 class="book-title">${book.title}</h2>
                <h3 class="book-author">By ${book.author}</h3>
                <p class="book-pages">Pages: ${book.pages}</p>
                <p>ISBN: ${book.isbn}</p>
            </div>
 
            <div class="cta-buttons">
                <a href="${book.url}" class="read-more btn" target="_blank">Read More</a>
                <a href="#" class="delete btn">Remove Book</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        `);
 
        swiper.update();
    }
 
    static deleteBook(element) {
        if (element.classList.contains("delete")) {
            element.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        }
 
        //INIT SWIPER ONLY AFTER ADDING BOOKS
        let swiper = document.querySelector(".swiper-container").swiper;
        swiper.update();
    }
 
    static clearFields() {
        document.querySelector("#result-form").reset();
    }
}
// STORAGE CLASS
 
//EVENT: DISPLAY BOOKS
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", UI.displayBooks);
//EVENT ADD A BOOK
function getMovies(searchText) {
    axios
        .get(
            `https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=ISBN:${searchText}&format=json&jscmd=data`
        )
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            let path = `ISBN:${searchText}`;
            let data = response.data[`${path}`];
 
            let cover;
            if (data.cover) {
                cover = data.cover.medium;
            } else {
                cover = "./imgs/book-cover-placeholder.png";
            }
            let url = data.url;
            let title = data.title;
            let author = data.authors[0].name;
            let pages = data.number_of_pages;
            let isbn = searchText;
 
            const book = new Book(url, cover, title, author, pages, isbn);
 
            UI.addBookToList(book);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
 
// EVENT: REMOVE A BOOK
document.querySelector(".swiper-wrapper").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    UI.deleteBook(e.target);
});
 
//SCANNER CODE
document.getElementById("start-button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("search-input").value = "";
    let selectedDeviceId;
    const codeReader = new ZXing.BrowserBarcodeReader();
    console.log("ZXing code reader initialized");
 
    //GET THE VIDEO DEVICE
    codeReader
        .getVideoInputDevices()
        .then((videoInputDevices) => {
            const sourceSelect = document.getElementById("sourceSelect");
            selectedDeviceId = videoInputDevices[0].deviceId;
            if (videoInputDevices.length > 1) {
                videoInputDevices.forEach((element) => {
                    const sourceOption = document.createElement("option");
                    sourceOption.text = element.label;
                    sourceOption.value = element.deviceId;
                    sourceSelect.appendChild(sourceOption);
                });
 
                sourceSelect.onchange = () => {
                    selectedDeviceId = sourceSelect.value;
                };
 
                // const sourceSelectPanel = document.getElementById("sourceSelectPanel");
                // sourceSelectPanel.style.display = "block";
            }
 
            //DECODE BARCODE FROM CAMERA
            (() => {
                codeReader
                    .decodeOnceFromVideoDevice(selectedDeviceId, "video")
                    .then((result) => {
                        let searchText = result.text;
 
                        console.log(result);
                        document.getElementById("search-input").value = searchText;
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.error(err);
                    });
            })();
 
            document.getElementById("stop-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
                codeReader.reset();
                console.log("Reset.");
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    //GET MOVIES WHEN ADD BUTTON IS CLICKED
    document
        .getElementById("add-button")
        .addEventListener("click", () => {
            const searchText = document.getElementById("search-input").value;
            if(!searchText) return;
    
            getMovies(searchText);
    
            UI.clearFields();
        });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly :D
can I ask you what this line of code does? ---->  if(!searchText) return;

Comment: @Zakaria In your code, the listener is added for the first time when the first book is scanned, so there's always a valid code in the text field. However, my version adds the listener on load, so it's possible to trigger the listener when the textbox is empty. That line checks if the textbox is empty, and if so, immediately returns from the listener, avoiding errors that may arise because of invalid (empty) code